# firebase check if account connected with facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added multiple authentication methods(using Firebase) in my app. And also added the option of connecting different authentication methods.
Actually, the problem is there when the user has logged in with Gmail and facebook both, and both have the same registered email address. In that case, firebase creates a new user for the latter, which I don't want.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean you want to find provider information? [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#providerData) . 
if you are using android, there's [providerId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FacebookAuthProvider#PROVIDER_ID) should return facebook

Comment: Actually, the problem is there when the user has logged in with Gmail and facebook both, and both have the same registered email address. In that case, firebase creates a new user for the latter, which i don't want.